# Ubuntu iSCSI partition is not visible in lsblk

Tags: ubuntu, iscsi

Recently I have created iSCSI Target with **/dev/sda1** partition (**1Gb** with **ext4** filesystem created), and iSCSI Initiator. Every service works correct without visible errors. Initiator successfully logged in to get target device.

Output of discovery command from Initiator:

```
root@Nitro5:/dev/disk/by-id# iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 10.8.0.1
10.8.0.1:3260,1 iqn.2020-09.tech.biowar.storagesrv01.target01
```

Output of lsblk of SCSI devices from Initiator:

```
root@Nitro5:/dev/disk/by-id# lsblk -S
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL                 REV TRAN
sda  1:0:0:0    disk ATA      WDC_WD10SPZX-21Z10T0 1A02 sata
```

Output of lsblk command. Also from Initiator:

```
root@Nitro5:/dev/disk/by-id# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop1         7:1    0  55,3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop2         7:2    0    16M  1 loop /snap/foliate/1119
loop3         7:3    0  29,9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop4         7:4    0  29,9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8790
loop5         7:5    0  49,8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
loop6         7:6    0 290,4M  1 loop /snap/vlc/1700
loop7         7:7    0 240,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
loop8         7:8    0  62,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop9         7:9    0 255,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop10        7:10   0  49,8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/433
sda           8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2        8:2    0   391G  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    0   5,3G  0 part 
└─sda4        8:4    0 534,2G  0 part /home
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0  58,6G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   131G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0  42,3G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0   6,5G  0 part [SWAP]
```

But there are no unmounted SCSI devices in main lsblk list. I have no idea where is SCSI device and how to mount it. How can I mount my device? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first command you listed is a discovery. Server is sending the iSCSI targets available to the initiator. Now you should login the the target. You can use the following example:

```
iscsiadm -m node -l -T iqn.2020-09.tech.biowar.storagesrv01.target01
```

Afterwards, the following command will list the connected target and details. At the end of the output you will see where the scsi disk is attached.

```
iscsiadm -m session -P 3
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct. But I faced another silly problem. I had a port conflict when **targetcli** wanted to use **3260**, but another service **tgt** already used it. So I had **tgt** configuration on the initiator side, not **targetcli**. After I shutted down **tgt** everything started to work correctrly. But your answer is also helpful, thanks)

Comment: Great to hear that you resolve the issue. Yeah, 3260 is default port for iSCSI.